# Covariance matrix for sine wave extraction

Tags: matlab

we have added five sine waves with different phase and same frequency in matlab. we want to retrieve all the input sine wave back using covariance matrix method. kindly provide the solution for this.

Comment: Questions requesting working code written to a specification are off-topic as they are unlikely to benefit anyone else. Instead, describe the problem you're solving and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 7):

This is an unsolvable problem.  When you add two sinusoidal tones of the same frequency you get a sinusoidal of the same frequency (even the possibility of one with zero amplitude).  Adding five just results in the same thing.

There is no way to tease them apart again.  As if I tell you five numbers add up to a 100, which numbers did I use?